# Magento API adding a new complex type to catalogProductCreateEntity (extra attributes not being passed)

Tags: api, magento, soap

I am trying to extend magento to pass configurable products. I want to do do so by extending `catalogProductCreateEntity` . What I did was created my own module and extended the catalog modules wsdl by adding the following in the `<types>` tag. like so...

```
        <complexType name="catalogProductCreateEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="categories" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="websites" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="associated" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="super_attributes" type="typens:catalogProductLinkEntityArray" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="short_description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="weight" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="status" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="url_key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="url_path" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="visibility" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="has_options" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="gift_message_available" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="price" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="special_price" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="special_from_date" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="special_to_date" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="tax_class_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="tier_price" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="meta_title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="meta_keyword" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="meta_description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="custom_design" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="custom_layout_update" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="options_container" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="additional_attributes" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="catalogProductSuperAttributeEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="attribute_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="product_super_attribute_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="label" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="attribute_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="use_default" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="prices" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="catalogProductSuperAttributeEntityArray">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:catalogProductSuperAttributeEntity[]"/>
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
```

I created a new element within `catalogProductCreateEntity` called super attribute. Its type is `catalogProductSuperAttributeEntityArray` which is an array of `catalogProductSuperAttributeEntity` which i also both defined  above. When I do a call to the soap server, I do it like so...

```
            foreach($prodInfo->super_attributes as $super_att) {
                $sProdInfo['super_attributes'][] = array(
                    'attribute_id'=>$super_att->attribute_id,
                    'product_super_attribute_id'=>$super_att->product_super_attribute_id,
                    'product_id'=>$super_att->product_id,
                    'position'=>$super_att->position,
                    'label'=>$super_att->label,
                    'attribute_code'=>$super_att->attribute_code,
                    'use_default'=>$super_att->use_default,
                    'prices'=>12
                );
            }
```

All the elements are populated. it looks like this...

```
[super_attributes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [attribute_id] => 159
                [product_super_attribute_id] => 207
                [product_id] => 4659
                [position] => 0
                [label] => Shirt Size
                [attribute_code] => shirt_size
                [use_default] => 0
                [prices] => 12
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [attribute_id] => 70
                [product_super_attribute_id] => 208
                [product_id] => 4659
                [position] => 0
                [label] => Manufacturer
                [attribute_code] => manufacturer
                [use_default] => 0
                [prices] => 12
            )

    )
```

Now, I've also extended the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2` class to handle this new attribute. my problem is when I step through the code, magento only recieves 2 attributes within the array.

1. product_id
2. position

All other attributes are ignored. I've also empty the soap cache on the server and client side yet nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
<element name="super_attributes" type="typens:catalogProductLinkEntityArray" minOccurs="0" />
```

should be my newly created `typens`...

```
<element name="super_attributes" type="typens:catalogProductSuperAttributeEntityArray" minOccurs="0" />
```

within the complex type `catalogProductCreateEntity`